# Adding empty character column to pandas dataframe works weirdly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy-slicing

I have a dataframe to which I want to add new column 'being_narrative'. Dataframe info looks like this:

[image: Dataframe Info]

Dataframe has following row indices:

[image]

I tried to add a new column of string type using this command:

```
explain_instance_to_explain_df_sorted_top6['being_narrative'] = ""
```

However, it gives Setting with Copy warning:

> _main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

I don't get this warning when I tried using the above command on a different dataframe:
[image]

Morever, new values are not being assigned to this column

```
explain_instance_to_explain_df_sorted_top6['being_narrative'] = ""
for index,row in explain_instance_to_explain_df_sorted_top6.iterrows() :
   row['being_narrative']= str(np.where( row.obs_instance_to_explain not in (0,1) and row.features not in ('NUM_CASES'),' being '+str(row.obs_instance_to_explain),''))
```

after running above assignment, the new column is still empty:
[image]

However, this works individually, as seen here:
[image]

Seems like the problem lies with dataframe. What could be the problem? Thanks in advance!

## Update:

Tried using @Aryerez's suggestion to use .loc convention, by first deleting column and then use:

```
explain_instance_to_explain_df_sorted_top6.loc[:, 'being_narrative'] = ""
```

But got warning again, clearly there is a problem with dataframe:

[image]

Comment: To avoid the warning create the new column with: `explain_instance_to_explain_df_sorted_top6.loc[:, 'being_narrative'] = ""`. As for the output you get, it's just the index and the values  of the column, which are empty strings, and therefore invisiable.

Comment: @Aryerez tried using iloc convention, still getting warning as can be seen in update in question above. Also, sorry I misunderstood index values, but problem does lie because when I try to assign new values to that column using df.iterrows() convention, it doesn't get assigned at all. Will update this info in question.